# PITest Issue: property 'mainClass' is final and cannot be changed any further

Tags: java, gradle, pitest

I have recently upgraded my project from `Java 8` to `Java 11` alongside `Gradle 6.5`.
However, when I run the command `./gradlew pitest` I receive the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':pitest'.
> The value for task ':pitest' property 'mainClass' is final and cannot be changed any further.
```

Here is my `pitest` set-up in my `build.gradle`:

```
pitest {
    pitestVersion = '1.4.3'
    targetClasses = ['com.myproject.*']
    excludedClasses = [
            'com.myproject.configuration.*',
            'com.myproject.controller.*',
    ]
    threads = 10
    enableDefaultIncrementalAnalysis = true
    historyInputLocation = ['build/reports/pitest/fastermutationtesting']
    historyOutputLocation = ['build/reports/pitest/fastermutationtestingoutput']
    outputFormats = ['XML', 'HTML']
    timestampedReports = true
    mutationThreshold = 90   
}
```

and here are my `pitest` related dependencies:

```
Plugins{
       id "info.solidsoft.pitest" version '1.3.0'
}

testCompile 'info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.3.0'
```

I am not sure where this `mainClass` property is coming from and have not found any related answers or documentation on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by upgrading the dependency versions to:

```
id "info.solidsoft.pitest" version '1.5.1'
```

and

```
testCompile 'info.solidsoft.gradle.pitest:gradle-pitest-plugin:1.4.0'
```

after increasing the dependency versions, the command `./gradlew pitest` was working as normal and the pitests were running fine.

Comment: I still have the same problem even with the versions you've specified. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: @spartanhooah perhaps try using the latest available version of the dependencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.solidsoft.pitest/info.solidsoft.pitest.gradle.plugin?repo=gradle-plugins